# Is it possible to start an NSURLConnection multiple times?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm setting up a class to manage the download of some data. Due to the spec it has to be downloaded multiple times (as it may change). I can't change that but I have a question.

If I create a class that is dedicated to downloading the data so it is an `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` etc...

Can I store the `NSURLConnection` as a property and set it up in the init and then reuse the same connection each time?

Or should I store the `NSURLRequest` and use the same request in a new connection each time?

The reason I ask is that the docs for `NSURLConnection` state...

```
"You cannot reschedule a connection after it has started."
```

and I'm not 100% sure what that means.

Comment: you have to create a new connecten each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as each time you have a unique object that creates the NSURLConnection. This is simply stating you can't have the same object "reschedule" a connection, mid connection.

Never hurts to run a simple test.